# EventKit permission

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

I would like my `EventKit` to request permission to the calendar when an event is attempted to be added to the calendar with access denied. It is only asking the first time the app is used and if you deny access in the settings it will not prompt the user to grant access again. Please help.

Extra Credit: I would also like it to check if the event already exists in the calendar, and if so, edit it. Any help with this as well would be appreciated!!

Here is my code:

```
func addToCalendar(){
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()

    let startDate = NSDate()
    let endDate = startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60 * 60) // One hour

    if (EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Event) != EKAuthorizationStatus.Authorized) {
        eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(.Event, completion: {
            granted, error in
            self.createEvent(eventStore, title: "\(self.meal.text!)", startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
        })
    } else {
        createEvent(eventStore, title: "\(self.meal.text!)", startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
    }
}

func createEvent(eventStore: EKEventStore, title: String, startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) {
    let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)

    event.title = title
    event.startDate = startDate
    event.endDate = endDate
    event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
    event.notes = "\(self.Recipe.text!) - See Meal Planning on Listacular"

    do {
        try eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent)
        savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier
    } catch {

        print("Denied")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You directly cannot prompt user to grant access again. But you can show user popup about the permission status and can request to enable the permission from device settings. Here is an example in objective-c

```
    EKEventStore *store = [EKEventStore new];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (!granted)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertController* alertController=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Access to Calendar is Restricted" message:@"To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Calendar Settings for this app else Continue to create party without saving it to your Calendar" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction *actionOK = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Continue" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)
                                       { 
                                          [self addEvent:store]; //your method
                                       }];
            [alertController addAction:actionOK];
            [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:kSETTINGS style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)
                                        {
                                            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
                                        }]];
            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:NO completion:nil];
        });
    }
    else
    {
        [self addEvent:store]; // your method
    }
}];
```

You can check store for a specific event using this method of EKEventStore. You need to pass event identifier.

```
- (nullable EKEvent *)eventWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not great at translating ObjC. I was able to figure it out, but am not sure how to use with the eventWithIdentifier to check and edit an event.

Comment: eventWithIdentifier method will return event if an event is exist in store with the given identifier otherwise it will return nil.

Comment: apparently I did that wrong. When it saves it should check `savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier` or does that just save the identifier and not read it?